# MacOS - legal way to get admin password

Tags: macos, cocoa, security, xcode4

I want to create application that use admin password to run some scripts in bash. For example:

```
 echo **pass** | sudo -S reboot
```

What is the best way to get it.

I looked [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000995-CH204-TP1) tutorial, and all of what I understood - it is how to run authorization window.

```
AuthorizationRef authRef= NULL;
AuthorizationItem right = { "com.my.app", 0, NULL, 0 };
AuthorizationRights rightSet = { 1, &right };
OSStatus status;

if (AuthorizationCreate(
                        NULL, 
                        kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment,
                        kAuthorizationFlagDefaults, 
                        &authRef) != errAuthorizationSuccess)
{
    NSLog(@"Could not create authorization reference object.");
}

status = AuthorizationCopyRights(authRef, &rightSet, kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment, 
                                 kAuthorizationFlagDefaults |
                                 kAuthorizationFlagPreAuthorize |
                                 kAuthorizationFlagInteractionAllowed | 
                                 kAuthorizationFlagExtendRights,
                                 NULL);
```

Is there a way to get password after this steps?

Or all of this wrong  - and exist another way?

Thanks!

Comment: No, of course the authorization API doesn't give you the user's password. That would be incredibly stupid.

Comment: Do I understand correctly - to execute some commands in the shell I should create second app, that will do it, and my first app should  invoke second app with rights, that it's got from authorization API? in this case commands will be executed from admin rights?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot (and should not) get the actual password. The OS doesn't even know what it is. This is on purpose. As you note, you should create a small helper program whose privileges you can escalate.

If at all possible, you should avoid the shell entirely. It is very fragile. It is much better to write a pure C/ObjC program that does just what you want and elevate its privileges.